# add sonarqube to jenkings without add dependency in build.gradle and do that with commandline

Tags: gradle, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wana don't add sonar in build.gradle  and before running the job of sonarqube add the plugin and to that in ci and after that run the script

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to achieve,pipeline can be set=up in different ways.
Try:

1. write docker-compose with Jenkins and Sonarqube
2. login to Jenkins(passwd  at /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword)
3. install plugins for Sonarqube(Code Sonar Plugin,Plain Credential Plugin,SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins)

Read the official [SonarScanner for Maven](https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-maven/) documentation.